# How to create several plots in latex using a for loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrays, loops

I have a bunch of arrays like follow:

```
a[l=3]=
(1, 8.099681e-01) (2, 8.099681e-01) (3, 7.399681e-01) (4, 0.000000e+00)
(1, 9.600000e-01) (2, 9.600000e-01) (3, 8.800000e-01) (4, 0.000000e+00)

a[l=4]=
(1, 8.099681e-01) (2, 8.099681e-01) (3, 7.699681e-01) (4, 0.000000e+00)
(1, 9.600000e-01) (2, 9.600000e-01) (3, 9.200000e-01) (4, 0.000000e+00)
```

and I want to create some figures for each array automatically (as I have lots of them). The plot that I want to create is the following:

```
    \begin{figure}
        \subfigure[$l=3$]{ % array l=3
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[]
        \addplot[]
            coordinates { % Precision
(1, 8.099681e-01) (2, 8.099681e-01) (3, 7.399681e-01) (4, 0.000000e+00)
            };
        \addplot[]
            coordinates { % Recall
            (1, 9.600000e-01) (2, 9.600000e-01) (3, 8.800000e-01) (4, 0.000000e+00)
            };
            \legend{Precision, Recall}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \subfigure[$l=4$]{ % array l=4
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[]
        \addplot[]
            coordinates { % Precision
            (1, 8.099681e-01) (2, 8.099681e-01) (3, 7.699681e-01) (4, 0.000000e+00)
            };
        \addplot[]
            coordinates { % Recall
            (1, 9.600000e-01) (2, 9.600000e-01) (3, 9.200000e-01) (4, 0.000000e+00)
            };
            \legend{Precision, Recall}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \end{figure}
```

The format of these arrays can be raw or any type, but I want my latex file to be simple. I was wondering if there is a way to handle this using a for loop and get rid of repeating tikz stuff?

```
\foreach \l in {3, ..., 15}
{%do something about array l
    \l
}%
```

Comment: If you can put these into a comma delimited dataset,  one column for each array, you can easily plot them using \pgfplotstable.  If you want to create them as macros, use \csname a\i\endcsname for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for reference here, I used a `for` loop in latex to do all these drawings. I first introduced a command and then wrote a for loop that reads the data and creates the plot.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} \linespread{1.65}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{arrayjob}


\newcommand{\plotprh}[3] {
\subfigure[$\ell=#1$]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        height=4.2cm, 
        width=5.5cm,
        xlabel={$k'$},
        ylabel={Percent (\%)},
        legend pos=north west,
        legend cell align=left,
        ymin=0,
        ylabel style={at={(0.09,0.5)},font=\small},
        xlabel style={at={(0.5,0.04)},font=\small},
        legend style={at={(0.42,0.06)},anchor=south west, nodes={scale=0.8, transform shape},font=\small,}
    ]
    \addplot[
        color=black,
        mark=square,
        mark size=3,
        ]
        coordinates { % Precision
        #2
        };
    \addplot[
        color=blue,
        mark=diamond,
        mark size=3,
        ]
        coordinates { % Recall
        #3
        };
        \legend{Precision, Recall}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
  }


\def\plotData{%
    {3}/{(1,8.627451e+01)(2,6.274510e+01)(3,0.000000e+00)(4,0.000000e+00)}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,0.000000e+00)(4,0.000000e+00)},
    {4}/{(1,9.215686e+01)(2,7.843137e+01)(3,0.000000e+00)(4,0.000000e+00)}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,0.000000e+00)(4,0.000000e+00)},
    {5}/{(1,9.607843e+01)(2,8.627451e+01)(3,5.686275e+01)(4,0.000000e+00)}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,1.000000e+02)(4,0.000000e+00)},
    {6}/{(1,9.803922e+01)(2,9.019608e+01)(3,7.058824e+01)(4,0.000000e+00)}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,1.000000e+02)(4,0.000000e+00)},
    {7}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,9.215686e+01)(3,7.843137e+01)(4,5.294118e+01)}/{(1,9.622642e+01)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,1.000000e+02)(4,1.000000e+02)},
    {8}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,9.607843e+01)(3,8.627451e+01)(4,5.882353e+01)}/{(1,9.107143e+01)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,1.000000e+02)(4,1.000000e+02)},
    {9}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,9.607843e+01)(3,8.823529e+01)(4,7.058824e+01)}/{(1,8.095238e+01)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,1.000000e+02)(4,1.000000e+02)},
    {10}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,9.803922e+01)(3,9.019608e+01)(4,7.843137e+01)}/{(1,7.391304e+01)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,1.000000e+02)(4,1.000000e+02)},
    {11}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,9.803922e+01)(3,9.215686e+01)(4,8.627451e+01)}/{(1,6.144578e+01)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,1.000000e+02)(4,1.000000e+02)},
    {12}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,9.607843e+01)(4,8.823529e+01)}/{(1,5.543478e+01)(2,9.622642e+01)(3,1.000000e+02)(4,1.000000e+02)},
    {13}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,9.607843e+01)(4,8.823529e+01)}/{(1,4.636364e+01)(2,9.622642e+01)(3,1.000000e+02)(4,1.000000e+02)},
    {14}/{(1,1.000000e+02)(2,1.000000e+02)(3,9.607843e+01)(4,9.019608e+01)}/{(1,4.146341e+01)(2,9.272727e+01)(3,1.000000e+02)(4,1.000000e+02)}}



\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \foreach \el/\recall/\precision in \plotData
    {%
        \plotprh{\el}{\precision}{\recall}%
    }%
    \caption{Results}
    \label{results}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```